# Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Srs.,

Tenho tido dificuldades no entendimento da documentação referente ao [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Não consegui entender como disparar o evento [`dp.show()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpshow) para um elemento específico, `$("#txtDataHora_01")` por exemplo.

Estou precisando de ajuda quanto a isso.

---

*Desde já, agradeço pela atenção*

Comment: Podes criar um jsFiddle? e/ou colocar o código que estás a usar na pergunta?

Comment: Sergio, obrigado pela atenção!
Mas talvez vc me entenda dessa forma: Preciso disparar o evento `show()` do elemento `$("#txtDataHora_01")` via Jquery. Lembrando que estou usando o Plugin Bootstrap 3 Datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

O evento show é disparado da seguinte forma:

```
$("#txtDataHora_01").datepicker('show');
```

Comment: Fernando Medeiros, obrigado pela tentativa em ajudar! 
`$("#txtDataHora_01").datepicker('show');` não dispara o evento. Lembro que estou usando o Plugin [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Ele difere em muito da versão anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtDataHora_01").datetimepicker();

    $("#txtDataHora_01").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        //Seu evento aqui.
    });
});
```

Dessa forma, acredito que toda vez que for alterado o seu campo, seu evento será disparado.